# Return the whole line that contains a match using regular expressions in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose I have the following string:

```
string input = "Hello world\n" + 
               "Hello foobar world\n" +
               "Hello foo world\n";
```

I have a regex pattern (as specified by the user of the tool I'm writing) of `"foobar"`.

I want to return the entire line of each line in `input` that match the expression `foobar`.  So in this example, the output should be `Hello foobar world`.

If the pattern were `"foo"`, I'd want to return:

> Hello foobar world
>   Hello foo word

Is this possible?

The code I have is

```
string pattern = "foobar";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern)
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Running this will output:

> foobar

Rather than:

> Hello foobar world

If `string pattern = "foo";` then the output is:

> foo
>   foo

Rather than:

> Hello foobar world
>   Hello foo world

I've also tried:

```
// ...
Console.WriteLine(m.Result("$_")); // $_ is replacement string for whole input
// ...
```

But this results in the whole of `input` for each match in the string (when the pattern is `foo`):

> Hello world
>   Hello foobar world
>   Hello foo world
>   Hello world
>   Hello foobar world
>   Hello foo world

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surround your regex phrase with .* and .* so that it pick up the entire line.

```
string pattern = ".*foobar.*";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern)
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(input))
{
     Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: Right.  Now i feel like an idiot.  I was about to run the regex over each line in `input.Split('\n')` in one case (the one described in my question), and just over `input` if the user specified an output pattern.  Your solution is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can use the following:

```
Regex.Matches(input, @".*(YourSuppliedRegexHere).*");
```

This works because the . character matches anything **but** the newline (\n) chracter.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.  Initially I didn't want to change the pattern because the user specified it, rather than my code, but this is simple enough.